# PHP Windows require_once ignored

Tags: php, require

My problem is,

This is the file that is being included ,

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "****";
$dbpass = "***";
$dbname = "****";

$MYSQL_ERRNO = "";
$MYSQL_ERROR = "";

// Connect To Database
function db_connect() {
global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname;
global $MYSQL_ERRNO, $MYSQL_ERROR;

$link_id = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(!$link_id) {
$MYSQL_ERRNO = 0;
$MYSQL_ERROR = "Connection failed to $dbhost.";
return 0;
}
else if(!mysql_select_db($dbname)) {
$MYSQL_ERRNO = mysql_errno();
$MYSQL_ERROR = mysql_error();
return 0;
}
else return $link_id;
}
?>
```

The main file has the following code to make db connection ,

```
<?php
require_once 'file.php';
$link_id = db_connect($dbname);
......
?>
```

But i got function undefined error.

Using Apache in Windows with PHP 5.3

Comment: Have you tried it with brackets? require_once('file.php'); -- And are you sure its pointing to the correct location? Try to put an echo in your file.php to see if you see that printed to the screen.

Comment: no, it didn't print it. Tried with brackets.

Comment: require_once...Are you already requiring the file somewhere else? Try with a simple require() to see if that works

Comment: As you say in the answer below, the code here is only an example, and I think this code would work unless file.php is not found. So, could you post the real content of your 2 files and which variable is undefined ?

Comment: @Ajay That obviously means that the either the code never reaches your require_once statement, or the path to the file that you want to include is wrong. Check everything. Using echo to debug this routine should help alot.

Comment: @Molochdaa i've edited it to include the original code.

Comment: @w00 i think mostly the first case

Comment: Try to close the db_connect function (there is a missing curly brace in your example) and test the file with php file.php to check if it is error free

Comment: @Brad may i know its path in windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [strange php problem... require_once ignored on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283629/strange-php-problem-require-once-ignored-on-windows)

Comment: @Eineki i didn't find one. can you specify the place ?

Comment: @Ajay mine fault, I've missed the last brace on cut'n'paste. Sorry

Comment: It's working properly if i insert the file directly.

Comment: Just to test, what happens if you just `require` it rather than `require_once`?

Comment: @slugonamission still the same

Comment: What happens if at the top of the main file, you put `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Comment: @AJay, How do I know where your error log is?  It depends on your configuration!  It could be anywhere on your file system, or even within your Windows event log.

Comment: @slugonamission  only the function undefined error.

Comment: @Brad I can find it in Linux but i'm using php in windows for testing purpose so i didn't know the path.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. You're supplying a parameter to db_connect, but it doesn't expect any.

Comment: Okay. As another sanity check, what if you echo `$dbuser` or something straight after the include line?

Comment: @Ajay, All you have to do is go into PHP.ini and look at your error logging settings.  If you don't know where your PHP.ini is, run `phpinfo()` within your script.  (In fact, `phpinfo()` probably also tells you your error logging configuration.)

Comment: @slugonamission  Notice: Undefined variable: dbuser

Comment: I'm out of ideas then if no more errors are reported

Comment: error_log has no value . Will be re-installing it. Just curious does Avast script shield creates problem. But disabled it & tried though still it persists.

Comment: just updated to latest php still it persits ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Check relative paths for your includes.

2) Just because the PHP documentation says you can use `require_once` without parenthesis doesn't mean you should.  Stay consistent, use `require_once("file.php");`.

3) Be consistent with curly braces in your function.  You're missing one or two up there.  I'd like to know if you rewrite your function the following way if it works:

```
function db_connect() {
    global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $MYSQL_ERRNO, $MYSQL_ERROR;
    $link_id = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if ($link_id === false) {
        $MYSQL_ERRNO = 0;
        $MYSQL_ERROR = "Connection failed to $dbhost.";
        return 0;
    } elseif (mysql_select_db($dbname) === false) {
        $MYSQL_ERRNO = mysql_errno();
        $MYSQL_ERROR = mysql_error();
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $link_id;
    }
}
```

And remember, checking your web server error logs usually helps.

*Edit:*

According to the comments for this answer, you're not including the file you think you are.  Use an absolute path for the include so you're 100% sure of the file being included.

Comment: Tried all not working still. I get this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_connect() in ....

Comment: According to how you wrote the function, you shouldn't be trying to call it with "$link_id = db_connect($dbname);".  You should be doing "$link_id = db_connect();".  You have no function called db_connect() that has any arguments.

Comment: Then you aren't including the file you think you are.  It's including *something*, because a require_once() that can't load the requested file will cause a hard failure.  Put an echo statement into the file you *think* you're including to see if it fires.

Comment: Then you're not including the file you think you are, simple as that.  Try to use the absolute path of the file you want to include instead of relying on the relative path.

Comment: this answer makes absolutely no sense and can't help anything.

Comment: ok i've reinstalled apache, php and mysql and the problem is solved. Thanks to all for your help.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: had you been reading the thread as it developed I'm sure it would make more sense to you.

Comment: Trolls are cool.  Enjoy your lack of reading comprehension, Shrapnel.

Answer (score 0):

A logic.
Sometimes we need it.

Let's sort out your case.

1. you can see whatever "function undefined error." (Although I'd prefer literal and exact PHP error messages as they contain A LOT of useful information, let's assume it's regular PHP error thrown right in this place).
2. We can conclude from the (1) that you can see alll errors occurred.
3. So, from (2) we can tell the if there was a file not found error, you'd be notified of it.
4. So, we can assume from (3) that there is no error and file being included correctly.

What's next?
The most possible reason for you getting this error is the wrong code you posted here.
For example, if you include your file not as `file.php` but as `http://example.com/file.php` the result will be exactly as described.
Or there can be 2 files named 'file.php', one contains the function definition and another without it.
Or there can be a typo in the function's name as well.

So, you just have to double check your names and **print some debugging info** to be sure you are including the right file and calling the right function.